# Creating a Map Reduce Function in Python from edge list

Tags: dictionary, mapreduce, key

I need some help creating a Map Reduce function in Python from an edge list.

Given the following list:

```
A,B
A,C
A,D
B,C
C,A
C,B
D,A
```

My code should follow the format below.  My goal is to display a degree list along with the count of degrees.

```
map(key, value):
//key: document name; value: text of the document
    for each word w in value:
        emit(w, 1)

reduce(key, values):
//key: a word; value: an iterator over counts
    result = 0
    for each count v in values:
        result += v
        emit(key, result)
```

Loops have always been a struggle for me.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

The output should be as follows:

```
Degree     Count
1           2
2           1
3           1
```

The code should work for any data set similarly formatted

So, as I understand it, I need to count the number of different values each letter is paired with--this would be the "degree" (A, for example, is degree 3), and then total the pairs according to the degree--this would be the "count".

Could the key be the pair of values?

```
map(key, value):
//key: document name; value: text of the document
    for each word w in value:
        emit([x,y], 1)
```

Comment: Seems like you posted the word count example. What are the column labels in your input and your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if MapReduce is the best way to approach this problem, but I think the following makes sense.

First Map each Vertex-Edge pair to the (Vertex, 1). Then Reduce by summing the counts for each Vertex.

```
map(key, value):
//key: vertex; value: edge
    emit(key, 1)

reduce(key, values):
//key: vertex; value: an iterator over counts
    result = 0
    for each count v in values:
        result += v
        emit(key, result)
```

This assumes that the input rows are unique.